# Windows session opening with Google Gsuite users?

Tags: windows, session, google-apps

I'm looking for a solution to use Google Gsuite to manage sessions from all our Windows stations. I do not find any solution after a Google search.

Have you any ideas ?
I thought about Samba connected on GSuite SSO but I did'nt find a corresponding project.

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks for sharing,
David.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible. I investigated this last year.
Google "may" have plans to extend its IdP for this, but it is not yet publicly announced if that is the case.
Chromebooks are currently the Google response to replacing windows workstations (with Citrix for legacy apps)...